# How to create angular directive for spinner?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, directive

I work on project and used ngx-spinner library and now want to make directive for this spinner and write the HTML code inside directive

```
<ngx-spinner type="ball-scale-multiple" [fullScreen]="false" size="" style="width: 100px;" bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)">loading ...</ngx-spinner>
```

how can i do that

Comment: You mean you want to make a component that renders the spinner as shown above?

Comment: No , I want to create a directive of type component

Comment: Yes, so you want a Component. The only directive with actual template.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update the question to show what it is you want and how you want to use it.  I'm not quite clear on what it is you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found is to create separate component for the spinner

```
<ngx-spinner type="ball-scale-multiple" [fullScreen]="false" size="larg" style="width: 100px;"
bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
<p style="color: white;"> loading ...</p>
```

and the directive

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, 
    SimpleChanges, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
import { SpinnerComponent } from "../spinner/spinner.component";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appSpinner]'

})
export class SpinnerDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input('appSpinner') show: boolean;

    constructor(private ngxSpinnerService: NgxSpinnerService, private elementRef: ElementRef, 
        private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private templateRef:TemplateRef<any>) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if(this.show){
            this.viewContainerRef.clear()
            const spinnerComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerComponent);
            this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(spinnerComponent);
            
            this.ngxSpinnerService.show()
        }
        else{
            this.viewContainerRef.clear()
            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
        }
    }
}
```

and use the directive on elements in this way

```
<div *appSpinner="showSpinner">content</div>
```